# Node Options in Jenkins Pipeline Script

Tags: node.js, angular, jenkins

I need to setup a NODE_OPTIONS--openssl-legacy-provider for a Angular Project, but i need to add this option on my Jenkins Pipeline so he can run the command first then the build.

I tried to add the node option on mu package.json but isn`t working

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.